# How to install Windows 10 from an existing iso on my HDD?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multi-boot

I am running Windows 7. I have downloaded `win10.iso` to my HDD.

I need to install Windows 10 (dual-boot) without using DVD, USB or network.

How to install Windows 10 from an existing ISO on my HDD?

Comment: You can't since your running Windows 7

Comment: How many hard drives do you have in there?

Comment: One hhd and 2 partitions

Comment: hmm, yah I can't see it being possible with one drive. You could try shrinking one of the partitions to make a 3rd partition, then make that partition a bootable iso. I have a feeling you will run into trouble trying to complete the install to the same drive though.

Comment: He might have luck if it's UEFI/GPT (have the content of the ISO copied to an available FAT32 partition). But apparently it is not but MBR/BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the point of this question, since if you have physical access to a machine to reboot it, etc. you can certainly install Windows normally.

However, without going into detail, this is possible if you create a virtual machine with something like VMware that lets you assign a physical partition or drive to a virtual machine. Start the virtual machine and configure it to load from the ISO image. Begin Windows Setup in the VM, then wait for the first reboot. At this point, power down the VM, merge the contents of the BCD from the VM's partition to your own system partition, reboot your own PC, and let Windows setup resume from there.

The initial stage of Windows setup copies all required setup files to the local disk, and only after the first reboot (when your PC starts from the local copy and not from the WIM) does it configure drivers, etc to match your system.

I obviously haven't tested it myself and I'm not about to for you, but you can give it a try and see where it leads you.

EDIT

Another, less-hacky option: clone Windows 7 to another partition, then upgrade the one you're booted into to Windows 10. Windows Vista+ support being installed from a virtual CD/DVD drive. I haven't tried with the native Windows 10 ISO mounting (not that you have access to it), but ElBy's Virtual CloneDrive works great for OS installs in my experience.